# Qt QAndroidActivityResultReceiver handleActivityResult() hadn't been received any answer from activity which called by startActivityForResult

Tags: android, qt, java-native-interface

Function CallActivity::runApplication  normally starts an activity of other app by startActivityForResult, when I press button in called activity and return result back into calling app by setResult(RESULT_OK, intent); function CallActivity::handleActivityResult must had received answer, but nothing returned. When I call app from Android Studio app I received answer normally. What is the problem with handleActivityResult? How I can received answer in Qt app by handleActivityResult? Android 7.1, Qt 5.15.2

callactivity.h  **class was inherited from class CallActivity : public QObject, public QAndroidActivityResultReceiver!!!**

```
class CallActivity : public QObject, public QAndroidActivityResultReceiver
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CallActivity(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    Q_INVOKABLE void runApplication(const QString &packageName, const QString &className);
    void handleActivityResult(int receiverRequestCode, int resultCode, const QAndroidJniObject &data)  override;
};
```

callactivity.cpp

```
void CallActivity::runApplication(const QString &packageName, const QString &className)
{
    QAndroidJniObject activity = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod(
                "org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNative", "activity",
                "()Landroid/app/Activity;");   
    QAndroidJniObject jPackageName = QAndroidJniObject::fromString(packageName);
    QAndroidJniObject jClassName = QAndroidJniObject::fromString(className);
    QAndroidJniObject intent("android/content/Intent","()V");
    intent.callObjectMethod("setClassName",
                            "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;",
                            jPackageName.object<jstring>(),jClassName.object<jstring>());
    QAndroidJniEnvironment env;
    activity.callMethod<void>(
                "startActivityForResult",
                "(Landroid/content/Intent;I)V",
                intent.object<jobject>(),1);
}
void CallActivity::handleActivityResult(int receiverRequestCode, int resultCode, const QAndroidJniObject &data) //isn't called!!!!
{
    qDebug()<<"handleActivityResult"<<receiverRequestCode<<resultCode; //!!!!!RECEIVED NOTHING
}
```

main.qml

```
Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Button {
        onClicked: {
            clcallActivity.runApplication("com.my.startactivityforres",
                                           "com.my.startactivityforres.ActivityDate")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was in using QAndroidActivityResultReceiver separately but there is nessesary to pass his pointer to the QtAndroid::startActivity

> void QtAndroid::startActivity(const QAndroidIntent &intent, int
> receiverRequestCode, QAndroidActivityResultReceiver *resultReceiver =
> nullptr)